# bootstrap react JS global

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am new to react JS and stuck in a very basic issue. I am using Bootstrap 'Offcanvas' component but the problem is that the button to toggle it is header while the menu itself is in different file. I dont know how to define global const to manage it

**CONST**

```
 const [showSidebar, setShowSidebar] = useState(false);
 const handleSidebarClose = () => setShowSidebar(false);
 const handleSidebarShow = () => setShowSidebar(true);
```

**HEADER.JS**

```
<Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSidebarShow}>Show Meny</Button>
```

**SIDEBAR.JS**

```
<Offcanvas show={showSidebar} onHide={handleSidebarClose}>        
    <Offcanvas.Body>
      Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you
      have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
    </Offcanvas.Body>
  </Offcanvas>
```

Where should i place these consts and make them global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the state, that is needed by several other components above them. This is called "lifting the state". Then hand over the state or/and your functions to the components below via props. For example:

- Put state in App.js
- Import Header and Sidebar in App.js
- Give Header and Sidebar appropriate properties showSidebar, handleSidebarClose , handleSidebarShow

Please look into following sandbox for a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-mopsa-5f6us9